# ASP.NET Error on button click

Tags: asp.net

I am getting this error while clicking  on the button control of an asp.net page.NO idea what to do

**Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation**

I have  `EnableEventValidation="true"` in my page directive

Answer (score 0):

Set EnableEventValidation="false" as a starter maybe?  Are you doing anything in particular on the page, anything out of the ordinary?

Answer (score 0):

EnableEventValidation="false" will solve the error message.

It's usually down to javascript changing the values of list items on the page when ASP.NET expects that they will be unchanged from what was rendered on the server.

You'd probably need to post some code for people help further.